# node.js : res.send is not a function

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I can't really figure out what is wrong with this function for it to be saying res.send is not a function

```
exports.createEphemeralKeys = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {

console.log("this is the req",req)
var api_version = req["api_version"];
var customer_id = req["customer_id"]
var api_version1 = "2018-08-23"
// var customerId = req.body.customer_id;
console.log("apiver",api_version)
console.log("customer id ", customer_id)

if (!api_version) {
  res.status(400).end();
  return;
}
const key = stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: customer_id},
    {apiVersion: api_version1}
).then((key) => {
    // asynchronously called
    
    console.log("creating key ",key)
    res.send(key);
    return key
}).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
});

});
```

the error displayed is

> TypeError: res.send is not a function

how can I fix this?

Comment: What type of API call is this?  Stripe?  Firebase?  `res.send()` is something that the Express framework provides.  It's not part of the standard nodejs `http.ServerResponse`.  We can't really help much (other than guessing) if we don't know what type of API this is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote a wrong codebase.
`functions.https.onCall`. This method takes two parameters. Data and context where context is an optional parameter like this :

```
exports.fullName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
});
```

But you tried to use it like a response.
so I suggest you to use https.onRequest rather than onCall, and you will be able to use response.

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Use res.end Instead of res.send Cause res.send Is a part Of Express

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a firebase function call, so to send a response back you can just return whatever it is you want to send back (which you are already doing).

Just take out `res.send` from your function (the second argument is `context` and NOT `res`).

`context` holds info around user auth.
More info here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable